# How to extract filename of :w command in vim's autocmd?

Tags: autocmd

When I use Vim and type in the `:w` command, sometimes I will tap `]` or `\` by accident before I tap the Enter key because these keys are close to each other. As a result, I will get files such as `']'` in my directory.

So I want to execute some autocmd in Vim to check if the file name which is going to be saved contains such special characters.

I have searched through the Internet, almost all of them give the solution of something like `expand("%:p")` to get file name. But after testing it by myself, this function can only obtain the **current** file name instead of the one I passed to `:w` command.

Is there any idea of obtaining the file name passed to `:w` command in Vim's autocmd?

Comment: If you hit wrong keys a lot it's maybe time to think about improving your typing skills. You will benefit from more speed, accuracy and confidence. Fix the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! In fact, I'm not quite sure whether it's my typo or it's just something wrong with my keyboard because I haven't encountered this problem several weeks ago. Anyway, before I decide to further check my keyboard, I have to bother Vim to help check my typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose you to introduce a command expression mapping `cnoremap` on the `<CR>` character. In the expression you could parse the command line and adapt it if it is wrong.

Here is a (too) simple example that detect ']' in your `w[rite]` leading command and replace it with `\` waiting for your confirmation and do nothing otherwise.

```
function! CorrectWritePath()
  if getcmdtype() != ':'
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  if matchstr(getcmdline(), '^w\%[rite]!\?\>') == ''
    return "\<CR>"
  endif

  let l:cmdline = getcmdline()

  " Parse the cmd line
  let l:newcmdline = l:cmdline
  let l:good = v:true
  if matchstr(l:cmdline, ']') != ''
    echo 'match'
    let l:newcmdline = substitute(l:cmdline, ']', '\', 'g')
    let l:good = v:false
  endif

  if l:good
    return "\<CR>"
  else
    return "\<C-u>" . l:newcmdline  
  endif

endfunction
cnoremap <expr> <CR> CorrectWritePath()
```

Comment: For the match on `getcmdline()`, try `w\%[rite]`

Comment: Thanks @Ben! With you everyday is chance to learn :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works!

Comment: Wecome to Vim :-) Thanks for the feedback!